# How to dynamically add Drop Down Lists into Gridview datarows

Tags: gridview, dynamic

What I need to do is, when the user selects a value from a drop down list it will generate dynamic labels and dynamic drop down lists inside the rows of a gridview. The number of labels is the same as the number of DDLs and the number of these depends on the selection of the user. I succeeded at showing the labels, but not the DDLs.

ASPX:

```
 <div id="dvCoverages" class="TD">
                <asp:Literal ID="litCoverages" Text="Coverages" runat="server" /></div>
            <div class="MAD">
                <asp:GridView ID="gvCoverages" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    GridLines="None">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="LeftLabel"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="RightLabel"></asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
```

C#:

```
public void SetCoveragesDDL(EndososWS.CoveragesInfo[] objCoveragesInfo)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("LeftLabel");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("LeftDDL", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add("RightLabel");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RightDDL", typeof(string)));

        List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
        List<DropDownList> DDLs = new List<DropDownList>();
        int numberOfCoverages = objCoveragesInfo.Length;
        if (numberOfCoverages != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfCoverages; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                var tempLabel = new Label();
                var tempDDL = new DropDownList();

                tempLabel.ID = "label" + i;
                tempLabel.Text = objCoveragesInfo[i - 1].CoverageName;
                tempDDL.ID = "textBox" + i;
                tempDDL.Attributes.Add(">> Select <<", "");

                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    dr["RightLabel"] = tempLabel.Text + ": ";

                    labels.Add(tempLabel);
                    DDLs.Add(tempDDL);
                }
                else
                {
                    dr["LeftLabel"] = tempLabel.Text + ": " + tempDDL.SelectedIndex;
                    dr["LeftDDL"] = tempDDL;

                    labels.Add(tempLabel);
                    DDLs.Add(tempDDL);
                    if (i + 1 <= numberOfCoverages)
                    {
                        i++;
                        tempLabel.ID = "label" + i;
                        tempLabel.Text = objCoveragesInfo[i - 1].CoverageName;
                        tempDDL.ID = "textBox" + i;
                        tempDDL.Attributes.Add(">> Select <<", "");

                        dr["RightLabel"] = tempLabel.Text + ": ";

                        labels.Add(tempLabel);
                        DDLs.Add(tempDDL);
                    }
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            gvCoverages.DataSource = dt;
            gvCoverages.DataBind();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this

```
tempDDL.Insert(0, new ListItem(">> Select <<", string.Empty));
```

instead of

```
tempDDL.Attributes.Add(">> Select <<", "");
```

Comment: I may have not explained myself very good. The problem I'm having is that the DDLs are not showing in the rows, I need to know how to MANUALLY in the code behind attach a DDL to a dataRow. Thanks!